# How to load images to html from a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image

I am creating a program that deals a hand of cards, determines the suits and values, the win type and winnings for a poker game. I have got the program to carry out those functions but I need to display the image of the cards instead of simply the names of the cards on the webpage.

So far I have saved all the card file names into a array called 'imgLink' as shown here

```
function determineCardDescriptions()
{
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
  {
    imgLink[i]= "./Cards/";  
    switch(values[i])
    {
      case 0:  result += "Two of ";     imgLink+="2";   break;
      case 1:  result += "Three of ";   imgLink+="3";   break;
      case 2:  result += "Four of ";    imgLink+="4";   break;
      case 3:  result += "Five of ";    imgLink+="5";   break;
      case 4:  result += "Six of ";     imgLink+="6";   break;
      case 5:  result += "Seven of ";   imgLink+="7";   break;
      case 6:  result += "Eight of ";   imgLink+="8";   break;
      case 7:  result += "Nine of ";    imgLink+="9";   break;
      case 8:  result += "Ten of ";     imgLink+="10";  break;
      case 9:  result += "Jack of ";    imgLink+="J";   break;
      case 10: result += "Queen of ";   imgLink+="Q";   break;
      case 11: result += "King of ";    imgLink+="K";   break;
      case 12: result += "Ace of ";     imgLink+="A";   break;
    }
    switch(suits[i])
    {
      case 0:  result += "Clubs"    + "<BR>";   imgLink+="Clubs";     break;
      case 1:  result += "Diamonds" + "<BR>";   imgLink+="Diamonds";  break;
      case 2:  result += "Hearts"   + "<BR>";   imgLink+="Hearts";    break;
      case 3:  result += "Spades"   + "<BR>";   imgLink+="Spades";    break;
    }
    imgLink += ".jpg";
    changeTheImg();
  }
```

The function changeTheImg() I'm trying to write to display the images of the cards is as follows.

```
function changeTheImg()
{
    var source = imgLink;    
    document.getElementById("changeImage").src = source; 
    document.getElementById("changeImage1").src = source;      
    document.getElementById("changeImage2").src = source;   
    document.getElementById("changeImage3").src = source;   
    document.getElementById("changeImage4").src = source;   
    //alert(source);   
  }
```

It's then integrated into the HTML as follows:

```
<form>
<br>
<button type = "button" id = "Play" onclick = "poker()" class = "button"> Play     a Hand! </button> &nbsp; &nbsp;
<button id="clicker" onclick="Reset()" class = "button"> Reset Game </button>     <br>
    <br>
<img id="changeImage" class = "img" ></img>
<img id="changeImage1" class = "img" ></img>
<img id="changeImage2" class = "img" ></img>
<img id="changeImage3" class = "img" ></img>
<img id="changeImage4" class = "img" ></img>
<p id="test"></p>
<img id="coins" class = "coins"></img>
<p id="win"></p>
</form>
```

**It won't however display the images. I get five placeholder image objects on the page and the contents of 'source' come up in succession as: 
*./Cards/,,,,AHearts.jpg10Diamonds.jpg6Hearts.jpg5Spades.jpg5Clubs.jpg***

This style of code worked for a similar image file where I used if's to store the image file names (below), Using this method for the cards would be very difficult as each

```
 function determineWinnings()
{
  var money = [0, 10, 20, 30, 60, 40, 70, 50, 80, 90];
  result += "<BR>" + "Winnings for this hand are: " + money[winType] + "     cents";
if (money[winType] == 90)
  {
   coins = "./Coins/90c.jpg"   
  }
else if (money[winType] == 80)
  {
   coins = "./Coins/80c.jpg"   
  }
else if (money[winType] == 70)
  {
   coins = "./Coins/70c.jpg"   
  }
else if (money[winType] == 60)
  {
   coins = "./Coins/60c.jpg"   
  }
else if (money[winType] == 50)
  {
   coins = "./Coins/50c.jpg"   
  }
else if (money[winType] == 40)
  {
   coins = "./Coins/40c.jpg"   
  }
else if (money[winType] == 30)
  {
   coins = "./Coins/30c.jpg"   
  }
else if (money[winType] == 20)
  {
   coins = "./Coins/20c.jpg"   
  }
else if (money[winType] == 10)
  {
   coins = "./Coins/10c.jpg"   
  }
else if (money[winType] == 0)
  {
    coins = "./Coins/YouWinNothing.jpg"
  }
}
function changeTheImg1()
{
    var source1 = coins;
    document.getElementById("coins").src = source1;
    //alert(source1);

}
```

I know what I've done is probably totally wrong but If anyone has any ideas on how to fix it I'd be really grateful!

Comment: Should `values[i]` be `cards[i]` in the `switch` statement? And if `imgLink` is an array, statements like `imgLink += ".jpg"` don't make sense -- that requires `imgLink` to be a string.

Comment: hard to make any sense of this code, no idea what some of the variables are. Suggest creating a demo in jsfiddle.net with full code. Good chance you have errors being thrown in console which will be helpful clues

Comment: And instead of all those `switch` statements, just use an array, e.g. `var suitNames = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]; result += suitNames[suits[i]];`